# Usar ArrayList para guardar datos de diferente valor

Tags: java, string, arraylist

estoy intentando guardar diferentes tipos de datos en un arraylist, principalmente String e int para tener una base de datos de personas. Despues de buscar en formas de hacerlo me decidi crear una clase separada

```
class Persona 
{
    private String nombre;
    private int hora;
    private int dia;
    private int glucosa;
    public Persona(int dia, int hora, int glucosa, String nombre)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.glucosa= glucosa;
    }

...
}
```

Y la clase que usara estos datos

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Organizador
{
    private ArrayList<Persona> personas;

    public Organizador()
    {
        ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<Persona>();
    }

    public void nuevaPersona()
    {

        personas.add(new Persona(dia, hora, glucosa, nombre));
    }
}
```

Sin embargo, no me deja compilar la clase Organizador ya que no encuentra los valores de dia, hora, etc y no estoy seguro cual es el problema y que estoy colocando erroneamente, estoy perdido.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu aplicación no puede inventarse los datos! Tienes este método:

```
public void nuevaPersona() {

    personas.add(new Persona(dia, hora, glucosa, nombre));
}
```

Donde estás pasando 4 parámetros al constructor. Pero esos parámetros no son ni variables locales, ni parámetros del método, ni atributos de la clase `Organizador`... no están declarados en ningún sitio.

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
public void nuevaPersona(int dia, int hora, int glucosa, String nombre) {

    personas.add(new Persona(dia, hora, glucosa, nombre));
}
```

Para poder llamar a ese método con los valores necesarios, por ejemplo:

```
miOrganizador.nuevaPersona(5, 14, 55, "Juan");
```

Comment: Ya vi mi grandisimo error, gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Debes modificar el método `nuevaPersona()` a algo como esto:

```
public void nuevaPersona(int dias, int hora, int glucosa, String nombre)
{

    personas.add(new Persona(dia, hora, glucosa, nombre));
}
```

De esa manera podrás construir una persona pasandole esos datos como parámetro y adicionarla a tu ArrayList.
De la manera que estabas haciéndolo no estabas especificando los tipos de datos del objeto Persona, como está declarado en el propio constructor de la clase `Persona`

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que declarar los parámetros en la función nuevaPersona() en Orgnizador tal cual lo haces en el constructor de Persona:

```
nuevaPersona(int dia, int hora, int glucosa, String nombre){
  personas.add(new Persona(dia, hora, glucosa, nombre));
}
```

Lo otro es que puedes pasar un tipo persona en nuevaPersona():

```
nuevaPersona(Persona persona){
  personas.add(persona);
}
```

Aunque de seguro la primera opción es la que estás necesitando.